# Public String becoming null after being set

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having troubles wrapping my head around this one.

I'm setting the value of the dataTest in a method and I inserted a breakpoint in the method and I can see the value of the dataTest is set. However in a separate method the value of dataTest is null?
This is the all done in the same controller

```
 public string dataTest { get; set; }
 [HttpPost]
 public void Test()
 {
     dataTest = 123;
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public void Test1()
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(dataTest);
 }
```

What would cause this?

Comment: It could be many things, we need your code to know more

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]. Also, ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC 5 are unrelated, incompatible technologies, you are using one or the other, so use only one tag.

Comment: How are you calling those methods?  `HttpPost` implies that they're invoked by two *separate* requests.  In order to persist a value across requests you have to persist it somewhere.  Session, database, cookie, etc.  Class instances don't remain in memory between requests.

Comment: `preventDefault` doesn't do anything as far as the server is concerned. If you are making two separate calls, then they don't have the same object

Answer (score 2):

The object instance is different between the two calls. Unless you make the property `static` to hold a reference to the same object, it will be newly created each time you hit the endpoint.

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest Dependency Injection here, but if you are going to do so, please at least say "as a singleton instance", as otherwise it's the same problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Good point